# Data from 1 datagridview to other

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I got quite far already, but for this one I've searched the web for several days and tried several things but I just cant seem to get it to work. Do any of you have any tips?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnkopieren.Click
  For i As Integer = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 1
    If CBool(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value) Then
        'If DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = True Then
        DGV2.Rows.Add(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, _
        DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, _
        DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value, _
        DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
        '2 = voer, 3 =voerid, 4= drogestof, 6 = (voer)keukenlocatie
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

I get the error "**Invalid Operationexception was unhandled**" Apparantly, it don't like it when I want to transfer the selected data from 1 datagridview to a other bound datagridview. Is there any solution for this? Like I said,  tried fixing it myself and googling, but without results.

**Update**
Found the following code. This seems pretty logic and looks like it can do what i want. I reckon i have to place this in the function where the datatable is being build, but how does it now what data to get and where to put it?

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In rows
        dtRantsoen.ImportRow(DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row)
```

Dim rows As DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection = DGV2.SelectedRows
        Next
        'Assigns our DataSource on the DataGridView
        DGV2.DataSource = dtRantsoen

So, i think that goes here before the DGV2.Datasource part in the form load event.:

```
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
    'Gets the records from the table and fills our adapter with those.
    Dim dtRantsoen As New DataTable("tbl_rantsoen")
    adapter.Fill(dtRantsoen)

    'Assigns our DataSource on the DataGridView
    DGV2.DataSource = dtRantsoen
```

Comment: Don't assume the cause of the error.  Catch the exception and see what the actual message is and which operation is causing it.  In general I doubt you should be adding rows to a `DataGridView` directly, but should instead be building up a collection of some sort (even a `DataTable` would be fine) and then just binding the `DataGridView` to that.  Its name even implies this, it's a "view" of data not an actual persistence of data.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Case is here that i need a easy way to populate several existing cells of a new row in the first datagridview with the rows selected in a other datagrid. All the cells are connected to a database using a sql query.

Comment: The concept should still be the same.  Populate the data source to which the `DataGridView` is bound with the new data, then re-bind it.

Comment: Hello,Yeah, i was thinking the same. but the problem is that the data it was already populated with, also needs to stay, so i would just need the code to actually add 1 or more rows to the datatable with the specific data from the other datagridview in the right places. I populated empty datagridviews before, using the code as shown above, but this is new for me.

Comment: I also tried using a combobox in the datagridview and filling a other cell based on the combobox selection, but that doesnt work because i have to use data not yet entered in any of the database fields from the sql query.

Comment: Right now it looks like i wil ldo it a other way: Using good old textboxes to select the required data, a save button to save to the database and then refresh the datagridview. Unless anyone can help me figure out how to add to the datatable using the other datagridview(this would be the desired method)